# Is there anything wrong with sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])?

Tags: c++, arrays, type-safety

One of my colleagues has recently said that the above statement is not type safe and I should use something else as you need as much type safe structures as possible to reduce the amount of possible bugs.

Whilst I agree on being type safe, I'm a little confused as this is the type of code in question (only the contents and length of data[] is modified)

```
unsigned char data[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int data_len = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
```

Where is the part that is not type safe?

Needless to say, other than the comment, the colleague will not explain further.

PS: This is used to copy initialisation data into a class from the constructor, no C++11 compiler exists here, so we can't use std::array or other fancy array initialisation. techniques.

Comment: If `data` is empty we have undefined behavior

Comment: Also what if it was a 2D array?

Comment: UB, really? sizeof(data[0]) does not execute the `data[0]` part, just like `auto()`. I 'm not so sure about UB here.

Comment: Is there a reason to store integers inside a `char` array?  Is the array meant to be set to: `{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'}`?

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD no. `char`s in C++ can be represented as `int`s. The `int` corresponds to their ASCII value. So `char c = 65` means `A`.

Comment: @Dgrin91: It'll only ever be a single dimensional array in the case in point.

Comment: @Dgrin91 I know that `char` is ultimately an `int` and that `char` variables can be used in integer expressions.  I am pointing out that if the intention is to initialize with integer values instead of characters, then in all likelihood the array should be declared as `int`.  Additionally, a `std::vector` should be available even if the compiler is as old as the late 90s.

Comment: @Moose But tomorrow you get a new job, someone replaces you and makes it a 2D. Or something a bit more practical: an array of complex objects that may vary in size

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD ah, well I generally agree there but its not super important and it is possible there is a reason for it.

Comment: The problem is that `sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);` will accept things that are not 1D arrays, for instance, a pointer. There are type safe ways of getting the length of a plain array (and plenty of SO duplicates.)

Comment: @Dgrin91: any of those are major refactorings/changes. 1) it's their responsibility to check where it was used. 2) varies in size? that's not an array anymore. again, it's not your concern.

Comment: @CPlusPlus OOA and D: Changing the array to be declared as int seems quite wasteful considering that the values inside will only ever be in the range 0 - 255, and if they change the array to 2D or a complex list of objects they'll have a lot more to worry about than how the number of elements is worked out. This array is used to initialise a std::vector in the class that can't be initialised otherwise.

Comment: @Moose Okay, I am sure there are a plethora of design and compiler version reasons to implement a specific way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe your colleague meant that using this expression with pointers will give an unexpected result. This mistake is made very often by beginners. For example

```
void f( unsigned char data[] )
{
   int data_len = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]); 
   //...
}

//...

unsigned char data[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
f( data );
```

So in general case it would be more safely to use a template function instead of the expression. For example

```
template <class T, size_t N>

inline size_t size( const T ( & )[N] )
{
   return N;
}
```

Take into account that there is template structure `std::extent` in C++ 11 that can be used to get the size of a dimension.

For example

```
int a[2][4][6];

std::cout << std::extent<decltype( a )>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << std::extent<decltype( a ), 1>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << std::extent<decltype( a ), 2>::value << std::endl;
```

Comment: Yes, after trying a few other things I noticed that sizeof() allows some things through which may not be desired which become compiler errors when using a template. Errors before run time are easier to find and fix :)

Answer (score 2):

One possible problem is that if data is created on the heap with new, you won't get the length, instead some value related to the length of a pointer on the system you are on.

```
char* data = new char[5];

//sizeof(data) is dependent on system
```

Comment: +1, I tried exactly that about 5 minutes ago and got the result "1" instead of "5". I know exactly why that is but catching any such problems before run time is always a bonus.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof data / sizeof *data` is perfectly fine and typesafe. But you must be able to guaranted that:

- You really feed it an array, not a pointer
- Said array is not zero length

  - Up to C99 at least , int[0] would be a constraint violation and thus must be diagnosed. Many compilers allow it as an extension.
  - Up to C++13 at least, the same holds true for C++.

You can get a diagnostic if you didn't provide an array by using templates:

```
template <typename T, size_t n> inline size_t elements_of(const T&[n])
{
  return n;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the template method is better considering that nobody is perfect.

Comment: Just remember the other one than, if you ever need C, or are stuck using an ancient C++ compiler.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void fun(int arr[])  
{
  /* sizeof cannot be used here to get number  of elements in array*/
  int arr_size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); /* incorrect use of sizeof*/
}

int main()
{
  int arr[4] = {0, 0 ,0, 0};
  fun(arr);  
  return 0;
}
```

In C, array parameters decay to pointers. So the expression `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` becomes `sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int)` which results in 1 for IA32 machine.

Therefore, `sizeof` should not be used to get number of elements in such cases. A separate parameter for array size (or length) must be passed to `fun()`. So the corrected program for printing the numbers is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void fun(int arr[], size_t arr_size)  
{
  int i;   
  for (i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) 
  {  
    arr[i] = i;  
  }
}

int main()
{
  int i;  
  int arr[4] = {0, 0 ,0, 0};
  fun(arr, sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]);

  for(i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
    printf(" %d ", arr[i]);

  getchar();  
  return 0;
}
```